# How do I pick a flux cleaner that's safe for use without industrial ventilation?

Tags: soldering, flux

I was looking at getting this flux cleaner: [Fluxclene FLU200D](http://uk.farnell.com/electrolube/flu200d/fluxclene-200ml-aerosol/dp/298165) but then I noticed that in the [datasheet](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/63512.pdf), it mentions an inhalation toxicity of 300 ppm. That sounds like it's easily exceeded by just spraying the cleaner onto my PCBs, even if I have reasonable ventilation.

Should I avoid this cleaner or am I misunderstanding this parameter?

**More generally,** how do I pick a safe flux cleaner? I've used isopropyl alcohol and found it entirely unsatisfactory in dissolving the flux residue.

Comment: Hmmm, not sure this is an electrical engineering question.  I'm not sure I would trust "what some guy on the internet said" when it comes to questions like this anyway.

Comment: @JohnD Possible. I wondered whether this might be off-topic, but don't electrical engineers pick flux cleaners on Farnell using datasheets? That was my thinking :) Rephrased a bit.

Comment: The way I look at it, anything strong enough to clean off chemically processed tree sap is going to be strong enough to kill you.

Comment: Use water soluble flux. Then you might be able to find a relatively safe flux cleaner...

Comment: At most of the companies where I have worked a lab manager orders the flux remover and we just use whatever is provided, of course checking to be sure it's compatible with the type of flux.  The MSDS is always available, but nobody I know ever looks at it.  So I'm still not sure engineers are the right people to ask about the health implications.

Comment: You say you are unhappy with IPA, but I am quite happy with it, it is cheap to get, you need only a decent wipe (although I use it in an ultrasonic bath) and it doesn't harm you or any other things on the PCB. The spray you link to is similar to the more agressive stuff I have used in past, but always outside and still aware of the risk of 'intoxication' even then. It's very much not my favourite.

Comment: You haven't specified what kind of flux you are using (rosin, RMA, RA, water-soluble, "no-clean", etc). Start by doing that. Once you know that, *then* you can narrow down the list of compatible solvents to find the safer options among them.

Answer (score 1):

Cleaning Flux from PCB is mandatory if RA, RMA or Water soluble. If No clean flux is used, then no need to clean unless you intend to apply coatings which may or may not adhere properly. Kayzen and Zestron make non solvent based cleaners. They are saponifiers (soap) with high alkalinity which remove flux and suspend it. These cleaners require very good rinsing with water (deionized) since they have low resistance and can contribute to ionic contaminant problems. I have used simple green cleaner with remarkable results on personal projects. IPA is not a good flux remover unless immediately and as a temporary measure during touch up prior to a thorough cleaning with a saponifier.

Comment: I suppose I should have mentioned that the flux that I'm trying to clean off is from the flux core solder. I already use a no clean flux when needed. Maybe that's also why isopropyl alcohol doesn't do it.

Answer (score 0):

You could try a no clean flux like this one:
http://www.gotopac.com/AIM_AF_NC264_5_1GAL_p/af-nc264-5-1gal.htm
With this Flux you will not have to use a flux cleaner at all. Which may be best if you are in an area where ventilation may be an issue. Just be careful, the no clean flux does burn off quicker, increasing the risk of oxidation to your solder tip.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that if you're working on a low power device where battery life is a concern, then no-clean fluxes can lead to parasitic currents, shortening battery life.

I use "Flux Wash" from DeOX It brand, and it works very well. Sometimes I'll then wash the PCBA down with distilled water too.